# Mixing Prototype and jQuery

Tags: jquery, prototype

How can I mix jQuery and Prototype and use best of both worlds?

```
var htmlret = new Element('div');
htmlret = htmlret.update(response.responseText);


// There may be many .SOME-CLASS so use `invoke` to iterate through them
// $$('.clsProPicture').invoke('update', html.select('.clsProPicture').first());

htmlret = htmlret.down("div#dvltrProfilePic");
//alert(htmlret);
$('dvltrProfilePic').update();
$('dvltrProfilePic').update(htmlret);
```

Some jQuery methods etc

Comment: Why you would do that???????

Comment: i have hard time to stick with prototype. current project protottype everywhere and i can not just delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for that. It releases the `$` symbol, so you can use that for PrototypeJS and `jQuery` for jQuery. `noConflict` also returns the `jQuery` function, so you can assign it to any other symbol you want, for instance:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```